# function not defined on form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I have a javascript on a form that is supposed to do the following:

1. Somebody has to unlock a form by pressing the .aanpassen button.
2. on page load there is a check. Some values should not equal the mentioned thing and there is one value that has to be the same. (the checkStuff function)
3. When .statuut or .land has been changed the script should check for changes and rebind the form.
4. The check vat number function checks for the correctness of a VAT number.

When executing in chrome I get following error when submitting the form.
`error testVATNumber is not defined`

Does anybody knows why I am getting this error?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  function testVATNumber () {

    var newVATNumber = checkVATNumber (document.getElementById('vat').value);
    if (newVATNumber) {
      document.getElementById('vat').value = newVATNumber;
      return true;
    }  
    else {
      $(".validation-error#error").text("Dit is geen geldig BTW nummer.");
      $(".validation-error#detail").text("Vergeet de landscode niet (en voor België de leidende '0'). Gebruik ook geen punten of spaties. bv. BE0409773728, NL001234567B01, etc.");
      $(".validation-error#error").css("color", "red");
      $(".validation-error#detail").css("color", "red");
      return false;
    };
  };


  function checkStuff () {
    if (document.getElementById('statuut').value != 'Gepensioneerd/Op rust' 
    && document.getElementById('statuut').value != 'Niet-Actief'
    && document.getElementById('statuut').value != 'Student'
    && document.getElementById('statuut').value != 'Werkzoekend'
    && document.getElementById('land').value == '4cce53c0-20bb-e311-840c-005056040a5f') { // België
      $("form").bind("submit", testVATNumber);

      $("#vat").parent().show();
      $(".validation-error#error").show();
      $(".validation-error#detail").show();
      $("form").bind("submit", testVATNumber);
    };

    else {
      $("#vat").parent().hide();
      $(".validation-error#error").hide();
      $(".validation-error#detail").hide();
      $("form").unbind("submit", testVATNumber);
    };
  };


  if ('~@type_correctie~'=='verplicht') {
    $('input').prop('disabled', true);
    $('select').prop('disabled', true);
    $("button.bevestigen").hide();
    $(".aanpassen-letop").hide();


    $(".aanpassen").click(function(){
      $('input').prop('disabled', function(i, v) { return !v; });
      $('select').prop('disabled', function(i, v) { return !v; });
      $("button.bevestigen").show();
      $(".aanpassen").hide();
      $(".aanpassen-letop").show();

      checkStuff();
      $("#statuut").change(checkStuff());
      $("#land").change(checkStuff(););
    });
  };
  else { 
    $("form").bind("submit", testVATNumber);
  };
});
```

Comment: Your JS is broken: you've got a syntax error in `checkStuff()` - remove the `;` before `else`. Same at the end of `testVATNumber()`.

Comment: Thanks @mpf82 that fixed it. I am going to reread how to use the `;` signs. Those are still new to me.

Comment: Also refactor the checkStuff to be the submit event handler assigned to `.on("submit",function() {}` and use e.preventDefault() to stop submission and use $("#...").val() instead of document.getElementById

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any of those functions to be in document.onReady.

Any function declared in the document.ready scope must also be called from within it. If not, they lose that scope when the ready() method exits. So it does not exist in the scope you are trying to call it from, hence your error.